# Where can I read the 1966 letters opposing Stalin's rehabilitation?

Tags: soviet-union, political-history, stalin

On 14 February 1966, 25 notable Soviet scientists and cultural figures sent a letter to CPSU General Secretary Leonid Brezhnev urging against the rehabilitation of Joseph Stalin.  Another similar letter was sent by 30 further scientists and cultural figures on 25 March 1966.

The original "Letter of 25" was not published at the time. [An archived facsimile in the original Russian](https://www.sakharov.space/bio/chapter-4-the-turning-point) has since been posted on the website of The Andrei Sakharov Museum, but the text is a bit faint in places, and many of the signatures are very hard to make out.

My questions:

1. Where can I find a Russian transcription of the original "Letter of 25" (including the signatures) and also an English translation?
2. Where can I find a transcription of the later "Letter of 30", both in the original Russian and in an English translation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably mean “the letter of 13” (not of 30), which indeed has the date March 25, 1966.

The Russian Wikipedia has the articles on both letters, including the signers lists and other details. They also refer to the internet publications of the full transcripts

- The letter of 25: [Письмо двадцати пяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8),
- The letter of 13: [Письмо тринадцати (1966)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8_(1966))
- The full text of both letters, the note of the KGB chief V.E.Semichastny and other related documents: [in Russian](http://www.ihst.ru/projects/sohist/document/letters/antistalin.htm), [auto-translated](https://www-ihst-ru.translate.goog/projects/sohist/document/letters/antistalin.htm?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp).
- A partial translation of the Letter of 25 - in [Andrei Sakharov and human rights](https://rm.coe.int/andrei-sakharov-and-human-rights/1680a287da), pages 102-104.

All publications refer to different pages of "АП РФ. Ф. 3. Оп. 24. Д. 495", that is a particular dossier in the [Archive of the President of RF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_of_the_President_of_the_Russian_Federation). I guess thus that the primary source is not easily accessible.

I have not seen any full English translations online, but the letters are written in the standard official style, so the automatic translation mostly produces reasonable results.

Comment: The Sakharov Museum refers to a letter of 30, but I suppose that might be a typo or transcription error. Your answer would be much improved (and accepted) if you included a link to the original [letter of 25](https://kpss-ru.livejournal.com/90296.html), which is linked to from your letter of 13. Both are only in Russian, though easy enough to auto-translate.

Comment: @Psychonaut - I have update the answer with more links